# How is it possible to use a "new" as parameter in side another new?

Tags: java

Below is an example which kinda shows the advantage of composition over inheritance. All I dont understand is the piece of code in  class Testbus. which is

```
new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1()).drive();
```

I am not familiar with the above style of code. How is it possible to use a "new" as parameter in side another new ? whats is this type of passing parameter or argument called? Is there a name for it ?

Below is the full context which I was following Until I encountered "TestBus" class.

There is a class engine it has a method method start(). There is another class Bus it has a method drive().

```
//dummy class or prototype class for actual engine

class PrototypeEngine1{

public boolean start(){
     // do smething
return true;
}
}

class Bus extends PrototypeEngine1 {
public void drive(){
boolean isStarted = false
boolean isStarted = super.start();

if(isStarted == true) {
// do something
}else {
    // do something
}
}
}
```

Creating Buss Class which has a reference of engine inside it

```
class Bus {
   private Engine engine;
   public Bus ( Engine engine)
    {
      this.engine = engine;
 }

   public void drive(){

    boolean isStarted = false;
     isStarted = engine.start();
    if(isStarted == true) {
    // do something
    }else {
        // do something
    }
   }
}

class TestBus{
public void testDrive(){
   new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1()).drive();
}
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted won't actually compile, because in `new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1().drive())`, `PrototypeEngine1` doesn't have a `drive` method. Did you mean `new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1()).drive()`? Also, I suspect your first `Bus` class is meant to be a `StandardEngine` or something similar. Please show a [mcve] that actually compiles (and is properly formatted).

Comment: Your classes are not clear. Anyways... you can use new operator here since it is just used to create the object. You can first create the PrototypeEngine1 object and assign to a variable and use that variable inside new Bus(..) It is just passing new instance of PrototypeEngine which Bus constructor is taking as parameter to perform its operations.

Comment: Please for god sake add some meaningful title for this question.

Comment: Modifed the PrototypeEngine1

Comment: The code `new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1().drive())` is actually pretty straightforward. It first creates a new `PrototypeEngine1` object, and calls the method `drive()` of it. Then it takes the return value of the `drive()`, and passes it to the constructor of a new bus.

Comment: Why *shouldn't* you be allowed to use `new` in a constructor argument?

Comment: Yes skeet, I actually meant   new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1()).drive();. Please have a look at my code again.

Comment: Mc emperor, I made a small change, the closing braces should end at prototypeEngine()), not after drive(), like Jon Skeet mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new` operator is used to create an instance of a class. What's happening in `new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1()).drive()` is that an instance of `PrototypeEngine1` is being created as an argument to `new Bus()`.

To illustrate this concept, let's refactor the single line of code in step by step manner:

```
PrototypeEngine1 engine = new PrototypeEngine1();
Bus bus = new Bus(engine);
bus.drive();
```

These lines of code are practically equivalent to that original one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instances inside of a new instance creation (constructor invocation). There's no difference than creating a new variable and passing it through except for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1().drive());
```

> 1. new PrototypeEngine1() -> A new object of PrototypeEngine1() created
> 2. new PrototypeEngine1().drive() -> Call method drive inside  PrototypeEngine1 Class for my created object
> 3. new Bus(new PrototypeEngine1().drive()) -> Create a new Instance of Bus.Provide the returned value from 2 to be used by  a constructor inside Bus.

*Also your code won't compile since drive() method isn't there in PrototypeEngine1 Class*